# Upload Data From Excel Sheet to taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I have 4 Excel sheets like:

**First (35) Records**:
State Code | State Name

**Second (650) Records**:
State Code | District Code | District Name

**Third (6500) Records**:
State Code | District Code | Block Code | Block Name

**Fourth (650000) Records**:
State Code | District Code | Block Code | Village Code | Village Name

I want to upload from Excel sheet based on *State Code* or sequence hierarchical records to taxonomy.

Adding them one by one is very difficult task.

I have a module for Excel import, but matching of record of parent is necessary like : **State -> District -> Block -> Village in taxonomy**

So how to upload these records to taxonomy (with no headache)?

Comment: What is the module you are using to import Excel files?

Comment: i have used feeds Module

Answer (score 0):

Try [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv)

> This module allows you to import or export taxonomy from or to a CSV
>   (comma-separated values) file or with a copy-and-paste text.

[image]

Comment: I have already used this module but they were not manage the parent child relationship.

Comment: @KamalOberoi youre not reading the `README.txt`